# How to get the HANDLE of a process main thread?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I want to use the GetThreadContext function which requires a threadHandle as first parameter. I searched for hours, iterated over all threads in the program to find the main thread but it seems like nothing really works.
So I don't need an answer on how to use GetThreadContext but on how to get the right thread handle to call the function correctly.
Btw. I want to read and set the EIP to debug on of my programs. And please don't start recommending x64dbg or ida...

Comment: A process doesn't have a main thread. It just has one or more threads. Language runtimes sometimes subscribe special semantics to the primary thread, but the OS doesn't.

Comment: If the process in question has windows (HWND) it is possible to get the thread associated with that HWND and that is very likely the 'main thread' for that process. But plenty of processes don't create windows, so this certainly isn't any kind of catch-all. Also, you'd need to be careful to distinguish visible from message-only windows.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir "*But plenty of processes don't create windows, **and plenty of processes create windows in multiple threads**, so this certainly isn't any kind of catch-all.*"

Answer (score 2):

If the program has a window you can most likely treat that as the "main" thread even though Windows processes don't really have a main thread.

Call `FindWindow`+`GetWindowThreadProcessId`+`OpenThread`+`GetThreadContext`.

If the process does not have a window, you can enumerate the threads with the [ToolHelp API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_toolhelp/) and call `GetThreadTimes` to find the oldest thread and treat that as the "main" thread.

Comment: system always return threads in order which thay created. oldest thread - the first thread in array. so not need call GetThreadTimes

Comment: @RbMm That may be but I doubt it is documented behavior.

Comment: this is logical and native behavior. all threads in process inserted to process object via list entry (double linked list). new thread inserted to the end of list ( InsertTailList ). how system return threads on query ? go via this list from head to tail and fill array. as result all thread here in create order. nobody will be special randomize array. possible of courese enum threads in reverse order - from tail to head, but i doubt that this will changed. what else posibility you view, that threads returned not in order ? i base not on documentation but on simply thinking

Comment: Right, so it is reliant on implementation details and as such undocumented.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - this not simply "implementation details". this is only single possible implementation details. i alredy not say about - what you will do if 2 threads have the same create time ? and at all question unclear - how possible set context to thread if even dont know to which thread and which this thread is doing.